# communicate by using app service isnt work on uwp platform

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I create the wpf app and add the UWP (Windows 10) dll and winmd files. and then use use the wpf app to open the app service, the receive app is UWP blank app, cause some requirement i need about .5 second to sent the message back to wpf app. end up the connection will canceled about less a minute. if i want sent the data to wpf app any suggestion for fast way of IPC ?

Repro project:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgAR-fncMacb0ugThRIsoiAXnyP31Q

Comment: By design the connection between different apps will be closed after 30sec if there is no traffic. You will have to re-establish the connection when you need it the next time. Would that not work for you?

Comment: I try to reconnect the app service connection. But still not working.

Comment: To help diagnose this we would need more info on the code you tried and the errors you are getting. Ideally you could provide a minimal complete repro project.

Comment: Hello the sample app link is below https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgAR-fncMacb0ugThRIsoiAXnyP31Q

Comment: Tried your repro projects (App4 & WpfApp2) and it works fine for me. It seems like you just forgot to restart the timer once reconnected to keep sending more requests. After I added that, it keeps on going as expected.

Comment: Thank you i found out that, ill mark as answer.

Comment: I think you can just delete the question. There isn't anything to learn for other readers, so no point in keeping it online.